# MVC cascading dropdownlist onchange load another dropdownlist and partialview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create cascading dropdownlists where users select Country dropdownlist and then it populates the States in the second dropdownlist base on the selected Country. I've manage to do that with the code below. But how do also return a partial view that contains some other data with a list of States to bind to States dropdownlist when the user selects a Country?

Let me try to explain it. I have 3 dropdownlist (Countries, States, Cities). The countries dropdownlist would populate when the page is loaded. When user select USA. I want populate the States dropdownlist with all US States, but also return a partial view that would display some information on the selected USA country like population and the capitol. When user select a State (Ex: Texas). I want to populate the Cities dropdownlist with all the cities in Texas and return a view with some other data. The cascading is just like drill down of a tree. I can't use a tree due to some restrictions. Hence, I am doing this cascading dropdownlists. Is this possible?

```
public JsonResult CountryList()
    {
        List<Country> countries = Country.GetCountries();
        return Json(countries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult StateList(string CountryCode)
    {
        List<State> states = State.GetStates().Where(x => x.CountryCode == CountryCode).ToList();
        return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Home/CountryList", null, function (data) {
        var items = "<option>Select Country</option>";
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            items += "<option value=" + item.CountryCode + ">" + item.CountryName + "</option>";
        });
        $("#Countries").html(items);
    });

    $("#Countries").change(function () {
        var Param = { CountryCode: $("#Countries > option:selected").attr("value") };
        $.getJSON("/Home/StateList/", Param, function (data) {
            var items = "<option>Select State</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                items += "<option value=" + state.StateID + ">" + state.StateName + "</option>";
            });
            $("#States").html(items);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you need to return a partial view? you should provide more details as you question is confusing

Comment: Sorry. I've tried to explained it above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a neat way to do it. But you can always return a partial view and place items data in hidden fields or return a JSON with all items an html string which you could apply to your page. Personally I don't like these options.

Why is it so important to get items and partial view by one request? Why don't you just make two ajax requests? The first one to get the items (you already have it) and the second one to get your partial view. You can easily accomplish it with JQuery GET method. The code should look like this:

```
$.get( "Controller/Action", { param1: "value1" } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    $('#infoContainer').html(data);
  });
```

This way you keep you code clean, simple and easy to understand as you have one action to get dropdown items and one more to get selected item description.

Comment: @AnhLun hi there, you didn't make any comments to my answer, just wonder if it was helpful to you? If not is there is anything I can do to help you with your question?